# How to use Json correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to sent a Json from my serverside to Java script.

```
return Json("{\"Message\":\"A Mistake just happend\",\"Passed\":\"false\"}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I does work and I get everything but as a string. I want to ask if it passed. So 
I would have to either convert my `Passed` to a bool var or compare if it equals false.

I that  the right way to go or do I do something wrong with sending or receiving th Json?

Comment: You can pass an anonymous object - `return Json(new { Message = "A Mistake just happend", Passed = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass string to Json method, you need to pass C# object instead. In your case you can use anonymous object. So if you will replace:

```
return Json("{\"Message\":\"A Mistake just happend\",\"Passed\":\"false\"}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

with:

```
return Json(new {Message = "Something", Passed:false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

everything will work well.

Comment: thanks for your respond. This actually doesn´t work for some reason. When I change `Passed:`  to  `Passed=` there Is no syntax error but when I debug firebug shows this: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data'`

Comment: sorry, my Mistake parsed Json in my success Method in JS. Thanks it is working now!